# Unique code based on unique email address in mysql table?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have a mysql table which will store users email addresses (each is unique and is the primary field) and a timestamp.
I have added another column called `'unique_code' (varchar(64), utf8_unicode_ci)`.

What I would very much appreciate assistance with is;

a) Generating a 5 digit alphanumeric code, ie: 5ABH6
b) Check all rows the 'unique_code' column to ensure it is unique, otherwise re-generate and check again
c) Insert the uniquely generated 5 digit alphanumeric code into `'unique_code'` column, corresponding to the email address just entered.
d) display the code on screen.

What code must I put and where?

**My current php is as follows:**

```
require "includes/connect.php";

$msg = '';

if($_POST['email']){

    // Requested with AJAX:
    $ajax = ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']  == 'XMLHttpRequest');

    try{
        if(!filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            throw new Exception('Invalid Email!');
        }

        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO coming_soon_emails
                        SET email='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'");

        if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1){
            throw new Exception('You are already on the notification list.');
        }

        if($ajax){
            die('{"status":1}');
        }

        $msg = "Thank you!";

    }
    catch (Exception $e){

        if($ajax){
            die(json_encode(array('error'=>$e->getMessage())));
        }

        $msg = $e->getMessage();        
    }
}
```

Comment: 5 digit alphanumeric code would mean that the number of unique codes your system can contain is 60,466,176 unique codes.

Comment: What is the purpose of the 5-charater code?  If it is a function of the email address, how do you generate a second code in the case of a collision without using a different algorithm? If not, why won't a simple autoincrement sequence number work?

Comment: why do you need a unique code?

Comment: @thephpdeveloper: That's more than enough :)

Comment: @Jim Garrison: It's to add as a referrer URL, ie: example.com/5ABH6. Once the email address is validated (valid email and checked it does not exist yet), it should then assign a unique code associated to that users row, in the next column.

Comment: @Jacob: Referrer URL code at the end of the URL.

Comment: Would very much appreciate any help on this one. Thanks guys

Comment: 'unique_code' (varchar(64), utf8_unicode_ci) should be varchar(5) as you only want  character codes that are 5 alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @P4ul: Thanks :) Any chance you know how to fix the code to make it work how I require? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps:

**a)** I did something very similar to this where I was generating unique codes which were to be used as URLs. I wrote this to generate the codes:

```
private function _generateCode($length = 5) {

    $characters = 'bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';

    $string = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $string .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }

    return $string;

}
```

$characters is a string of "allowed" characters. We chose to remove the vowels so that there was no chance of making unwanted words :) You could change this. There are simpler ways to write it but we needed something quite specific.

You would use it like this:

```
$unique_code = _generateCode();
```

**b)** For this just wrap your insert statement in a select statement check for that unique code. If the code exists then generate another code and try again. One way you could do this is (NB: this isn't tested and it may be susceptible to an infinite loop if you happen to get into a situation where you've used up all your codes ;) And you should probably add a check to make sure the INSERT was succesful):

```
$unique_code = "";
$inserted = false;
// Keep looping until we've inserted a record
while(!$inserted) {
    // Generate a code
    $unique_code = _generateCode();
    // Check if it exists
    if ($result = mysqli->query("SELECT unique_code FROM coming_soon_emails WHERE unique_code = '$unique_code'")) {
        // Check no record exists
        if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
            // Create new record
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO coming_soon_emails (email,unique_code) VALUES ('" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']) . "','$unique_code')");
            // Set inserted to true to ext loop
            $inserted = true;
            // Close the result object
            $result->close();
        }
    } else {
        // Quit if we can't check the database
        die('Something went wrong with select');
    }   
}

// Output the code
echo $unique_code;
```

**c)** To insert the unique code just add this to your insert statement where $unique_code is the variable assigned the return value from the function above:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO coming_soon_emails (email,unique_code) VALUES ('".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."','$unique_code')");
```

**d)** Just echo the variable you assigned the code to e.g:

```
echo $unique_code;
```

Comment: @Shane Garelja: Thank you soooo much! I'll have a poke around with regard to the select statement. I've touched on it, but definitely need to understand the language a lot more. Great idea on removing the vowels!!

Comment: No problem :) Glad to help. Here's a wee pointer on your select statement to get you started: "SELECT unique_code FROM coming_soon_emails WHERE unique_code = '$unique_code'" - now you just have to figure out for yourself how to interrogate the result and determine whether you need to generate another code or whether you can safely insert the new email record.

Comment: Let me guess.. put $unique_code = _generateCode(); and that SELECT statement (and determining if $unique_code = any in the column) in a loop? I'll definitely be reading up on this one.. Thank you again :)

Comment: @Shane Garelja: How about this :)

if($unique_code = mysqli_query("SELECT `unique_code` FROM `coming_soon_emails` WHERE `unique_code` = '$unique_code'")){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($unique_code)){
    _generateCode();
  }
  $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO coming_soon_emails (email,unique_code) VALUES ('".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."','$unique_code')");
}

Comment: @jeremycollins - there were a few issues with what you had so I've added an example to my answer and commented so hopefully it helps you understand what's happening. FYI - some of the issues with what you had: 1) "mysqli_query" is the procedural style call and requires a pointer to the connection object as the first parameter. 2) You were assigning this to a variable called $unique_code - the query function returns a result object which must be interrogated. 3) _generateCode() was not assigned to a variable. 4) The INSERT statement referred to $unique_code which was a mysql result object :)

Comment: @Shane Garelja: Thanks for that mate. I'm slowly learning :) Found out you have missed a $ sign on the first mysqli->query. Also I cannot get this thing to work :/ Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PRIVATE in.. on the line of the private function. Even when removing the private and leaving it as function... the page runs fine but the unique_code isn't inserted?

Comment: @Shane Garelja: nor does $unique_code echo. really stumped :/

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more elegant solution would be to use MySQL to do most of the work for you, by setting the `unique_code` field type to `VARCHAR(5)` and placing a `UNIQUE` index on it. You could then use the query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE coming_soon_emails SET `unique_code` = MD5(CONCAT(`email`, NOW()))
        WHERE `email` = {$email}";
```

and your PHP code would look like:

```
while(!$mysqli->query($sql)) {
    // If the error that was thrown wasn't a duplicate key problem,
    // something else is wrong (ie can't connect to MySQL server).
    if($mysqli->errno != 1062) {
        // Error handling code
        break;
    }
}
```

Using this approach, moving to a longer unique code (eg 6 chars) is as easy as altering the `unique_code` field to be of length 6.

Comment: Thanks for that :) just trying the above approach and if no go, I'll test your one out.