# Auto-generate unique alphanumeric in DB?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 columns in my DB: email (primary), unique_code, timestamp

1. Users enter their email address and it is added to the DB.
   Each time a user does so, I would like the 'unique_code' column in that row to auto-generate a UNIQUE 5-digit alphanumeric (0-9, A-Z) code. I'd prefer the DB to do all the work on this but I don't know how.
2. The next thing is that I need to display that code to the user (the one corresponding to their row).

How do I go about both?

Thank you!

---

Field Type Collation Attributes Null Default Extra Action
email varchar(64) utf8_unicode_ci No None
unique_code varchar(64) utf8_unicode_ci No None
timestamp timestamp on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP No CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

INDEXES
PRIMARY BTREE Yes No email 7 A

**Edit: (Full code)**

```
<?php

require "includes/connect.php";

$msg = '';

if($_POST['email']){

    // Requested with AJAX:
    $ajax = ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']  == 'XMLHttpRequest');

    try{
        if(!filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            throw new Exception('Invalid Email!');
        }

        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO coming_soon_emails
                        SET email='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'");

        if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1){
            throw new Exception('This email already exists in the database.');
        }

        if($ajax){
            die('{"status":1}');
        }

        $msg = "Thank you!";
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO coming_soon_emails VALUES('email', SUBSTRING(MD5(UUID()),FLOOR(RAND()*25),5), UNIX_TIMESTAMP())");
echo "Something went wrong:" . $mysqli->error;
    }
    catch (Exception $e){

        if($ajax){
            die(json_encode(array('error'=>$e->getMessage())));
        }

        $msg = $e->getMessage();        
    }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>example</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

    <form id="form" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $msg?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" />
    </form>

    <div id="thankyou">
    Thank you! <?php echo $unique_code;?></p>
    </div>


</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307641/unique-code-based-on-unique-email-address-in-mysql-table)?

Comment: @Charles: Because I now want the DB to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(UUID()),FLOOR(RAND()*25),5) as id;
```

Or, how you'd be using it-

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES('email', SUBSTRING(MD5(UUID()),FLOOR(RAND()*25),5), UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
```

Comment: @kavisiegel: Sorry, misread that statement. Thanks I'll give it a try now.

Comment: Nope, it goes in order of the columns you specified. 'email' goes in email, SUBSTRING(UUID(),1,5) goes in code, and UNIX_TIMESTAMP() goes in timestamp. (disclaimer, these may not be 100% unique. I'm not sure how the uuid() function works)

Comment: This won't work. Taking only 5 characters from UUID() will make too many clashes and the first few will probably share the same 5 chars.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose you're right. I edited my original post to address that.

Comment: I added: $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO coming_soon_emails VALUES('email', SUBSTRING(UUID(),1,5), UNIX_TIMESTAMP())"); and it does not add the 5 digit code

Comment: @kavisiegel @Richard aka cyberkiwi: Added full code above. I would also like to echo the code back to the user when the thank you div is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the `code` column into a `unique` index that auto increments:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
    ADD code INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE;
```

Then set your auto-increment to start at 5 digits (e.g. 10000):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

You can probably combine that into one statement but I'm not that good :/

You can then use [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) to get the code column value

Comment: Will that be alphanumeric or only numeric?

Comment: numeric, sorry I missed the 'alphanumeric' part of that question. In that case I would use php rand() to generate a number with min=10000 and max=99999, and then swap out random numbers in that result with random letters (still with php). Then query the db to see if it exists, if it doesn't then insert, if it does then rinse and repeat...   I don't know of a DB only way to do what you want. Why does it have to be alphanumeric?

Comment: It's kind of like for short urls, I'd rather alphanumeric. Also more efficient if the DB does the random work.. rather than looping through the whole column for checks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in MySQL, you need a computed column, and they are not supported.

What you could do instead, is have a standard auto incrementing integer and then when you fetch the record convert that Integer (of base 10) to another integer of some base (36 in your case - 26 letters + 10 digits) which will give a string.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations. So what exactly do I adjust in the db.. ALTER something? And what do I have to change in my code to do the fetch and convert? I'll update the question in a second with my current table structure.. Thank you!